# Email Id validation in javascript

Tags: javascript, validation, email

I have two domains to check whether the valid email id or not it checks fine but when i am giving `@@` (double times) also it takes valid email id.

How can I check and stop user entering `@@@`

My code for checking valid email or not

```js
function validate() {

  if (email == "") {
    alert('Please Enter EmailId');
    document.getElementById("txtEmail").focus();
    return false;
  } else if (email.lastIndexOf("@") === 0 || !(email.endsWith("@ho.XXX.com") || email.endsWith("@YYY.com"))) {
    if (document.getElementById("txtEmail").value == "@ho.XXX.com" || document.getElementById("txtEmail").value == "@YYY.com") {
      alert("Please Enter Valid UserName before @");
      document.getElementById("txtEmail").focus();
      return false;
    }
    alert("Email Should be in @ho.XXX.com or @YYY.com");
    $("#txtEmail").val('');
    document.getElementById("txtEmail").focus();
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: `if (email.split("@").length!==2) ...`

Comment: `if (email.lastIndexOf("@") === 0 ||email.split("@").length!==2 ...`

Comment: Please do not remove your code - that is what I based my answer on. My answer does not make sense without YOUR code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't repeat yourself:

```js
function validate() {
  var email = $.trim($("#txtEmail").val());
  if (email === "" ||
    email.split("@").length !== 2 ||
    email.lastIndexOf("@") === 0 ||
   !email.endsWith("@ho.XXX.com") ||
   !email.endsWith("@YYY.com") ) {
     alert("Please Enter Valid UserName before @\nEmail Should be in   @ho.XXX.com or @YYY.com");
     $("#txtEmail").focus();
     return false;
   }
   return true; // allow whatever
}
```

Comment: Hi,@mplungjan,Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use [String.prototype.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

`email.match(/@/g).length`

Your code will be like this:

```js
if (email == ""){   
     alert('Please Enter EmailId');
     document.getElementById("txtEmail").focus();
     return false;
     }

    else if(email.match(/@/g) > 1 || !(email.endsWith("@ho.XXX.com") || email.endsWith("@YYY.com"))){
        if(document.getElementById("txtEmail").value=="@ho.XXX.com"||document.getElementById("txtEmail").value=="@YYY.com"){
         alert("Please Enter Valid UserName before @");
         document.getElementById("txtEmail").focus();
         return false;
    }
      alert("Email Should be in @ho.XXX.com or @YYY.com");
       $("#txtEmail").val('');
       document.getElementById("txtEmail").focus();
         return false; 
}
```

Comment: Hi,Mohamed Abbas, when i click  Run code snippet i got error like this `error:{
  "message": "Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal return statement",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 16,
  "colno": 6
}`

Comment: @Karthik this is normal because there is no `HTML` code. you need to copy it to your project or share the rest of your code with us.

Answer (score 0):

use the build in validator:

```
function emailValid(emailAddy){
  var email = document.createElement('input');
  email.type = 'email';
  email.value = emailAddy;
  return email.validity.valid; 
};

console.log (emailValid('ttt@gmx.de'));
console.log (emailValid('tt t@gm x.de'));
```

Comment: That is nice. However he still needs to check the endsWith and use a browser that supports the HTML5 validation

Comment: You just have to shake your head long enough to find a hair in the soup ...
;-)